# oracle identifier too long

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, identifier, composite-primary-key

New to oracle
Im trying to assign composite key

```
CREATE TABLE rep_contracts
( Store_id NUMBER(8),
  Name NUMBER(5)
  Quarter CHAR(3),
  Rep_id NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_idstore_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (rep_id, store_id),
    CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (rep_id),
     CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_store_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (store_id) );
```

and im receiving

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

Im aware that composit key identifier longer than 30 char
but if I cut identifier few character shorter ex:

```
rep_contrac_rep_idstore_id_pk
```

then I receive

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

I couldn't find any workaround

Comment: You have omitted the REFERENCES clause of both the foreign keys.

Comment: Er so the error in the question is not the error - you solved that, its got nothing to do with the length, the issue is *missing keyword*

Comment: @Alex yes but having the keyword too long "solves" the missing keyword issue! ;-)

Comment: You miss a `,` after `Name NUMBER(5)`

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned the script and incorporated the comments:

- added a comma after number(5)
- changed all names to uppercase to save pain later
- changed NAME which is an Oracle reserved key work to S_NAME
- changed the data type from CHAR to VARCHAR2
- added the references keyword to point to the table where the foreign key is
- renamed the constraint so it is not more than 30 characters

like so:

```
 CREATE TABLE rep_contracts
   ( STORE_ID NUMBER(8),
     S_NAME NUMBER(5),
     QUARTER VARCHAR2(3),
     REP_ID NUMBER(5),
     CONSTRAINT rep_cont_rep_idstore_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (REP_ID, STORE_ID),
     CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_fk FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES your_table(REP_ID),
     CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_store_id_fk FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES your_table(STORE_ID) );
```

Comment: `•changed all names to uppercase to save pain later` -- this is an irrelevant change. It only matters if you're using case sensitive identifiers (i.e. enclosed within double-quotes), which should be very much the exception when creating tables!

Comment: @Boneist Irrelevant if you know about case sensitive identifiers.  For someone new at Oracle uppercasing is a good habit.